# Camel errorHandlerRef not handling exceptions

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-camel

I have the following Camel route/Spring XML config:

```
<camelContext id="my-camel-context" errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="my-camel-route">
        <from uri="file:///home/myuser/start?include=input_.*xml&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&delay=6000000"/>

        <to uri="loggingBean?method=log" />
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="deadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="bean:errorHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="loggingBean" class="com.me.myapp.LoggingBean" />

<bean id="errorHandler" class="com.my.myapp.ErrorHandler" />
```

And the following `loggingBean`:

```
public class LoggingBean {
    public void log(Exchange exchange) {
        System.out.println("About to throw exception...");
        boolean b = true;
        if(b)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad code!");
    }
}
```

And the following `errorHandler`:

```
public class ErrorHandler implements Processor {
    public ErrorHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        Exception exception = exchange.getException();      
        System.out.println("Just received exception of type " + exception.getClass().getName() + ".");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the "*About to throw exception...*" log message from the `loggingBean`, but no log messages from the `errorHandler`. Camel just stops, but doesn't shut down. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception object is probably null in your handler, causing a NPE. To get the caught exception you can use:

`Exception exception = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);`

Comment: Hey thanks @bgossit (+1) - that works! However, I am now seeing that Camel is not shutting down after I print the exception. Is there a way to tell Camel to shut down if an Exception is thrown?

Comment: Do you mean shut down the route? You could do that with something like exchange.getContext().stopRoute("my-camel-route").